# Calculation of the Lie derivative of the fundamental one-form in three different ways

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, lie-derivative, hamilton-equations, co-tangent-space

I am a physicist who is trying to understand more formal differential geometry in the context of classical mechanics. I came across three ways of computing the Lie derivative of differential one-forms. The first two are consistent, but the third is not. I would like you to help me figure out if there is a legitimate interpretation for that case, or if it's just a mistake.

=== INTRODUCTION AND DEFINITIONS ===

For simplicity, let $\mathbb{Q}$ be a 1-dimensional manifold. The manifold $\mathbb{Q}$ has some local coordinate $q$.

We can then define the 2-dimensional tangent bundle $T\mathbb{Q}$. The tangent bundle has local coordinates $(q,\dot{q})$, with $\dot{q}$ a tangent vector at $q$.

We can also define the 2-dimensional cotangent bundle $T^* \mathbb{Q}$, i.e., the phase space. The phase space has local coordinates $(q,p)$, with $p$ a cotangent vector (covector) at $q$.

We can also define the 4-dimensional tangent bundle $T(T^*\mathbb{Q})$ associated with the phase space. The local coordinates of $T(T^*\mathbb{Q})$ are $(q,p,\dot{q},\dot{p})$, where $(\dot{q},\dot{p})$ is a vector tangent to $T^*\mathbb{Q}$ at $(q,p)$.

=== FLOW ===

Also for simplicity, consider the flow generated by the Hamiltonian function $H(q,p)$ of the simple harmonic oscillator on $T^* \mathbb{Q}$:

$$H(q,p) = \frac{q^2}{2} + \frac{p^2}{2}.$$

The integral curves in local coordinates are the solutions of the Hamilton differential equations

$$\dot{q} \frac{\partial}{\partial q} + \dot{p}\frac{\partial}{\partial p} = p \frac{\partial}{\partial q} - q \frac{\partial}{\partial p}.$$

Note that the left-hand side is necessarily a vector field defined on $T(T^*\mathbb{Q})$. By contrast, the right-hand side can be seen as a vector field restricted to $T^* \mathbb{Q}$. Let us define these vector fields separately:

$$\Delta_H = p \frac{\partial}{\partial q} - q \frac{\partial}{\partial p},\;\; \Delta_T = \dot{q} \frac{\partial}{\partial q} + \dot{p}\frac{\partial}{\partial p},$$

so that the Hamilton equations are given by the constraint $\Delta_H = \Delta_T$. Note that we denote the contraction with respect to a field $\Delta$ as $i_\Delta$.

Now I am interested in calculating the Lie derivative of the fundamental one-form

$$\theta = p\,dq.$$

We can conceptualize this either as a one-form defined on $T^* \mathbb{Q}$,

$$\theta = p\,dq + 0\,dp,$$

or as a one-form defined on $T(T^* \mathbb{Q})$,

$$\theta = p\,dq + 0\,dp + 0\,d\dot{q} + 0\,d\dot{p}.$$

=== #1: LIE DERIVATIVE ON $T^*\mathbb{Q}$ ===

First let's interpret $\theta$ as a one-form on $T^*\mathbb{Q}$ and take the Lie derivative of $\theta$ with respect to the vector field $\Delta_H$ on $T^*\mathbb{Q}$. We get:

$$\begin{align}
L_{\Delta_H}(\theta) &= d(i_{\Delta_H}\theta) + i_{\Delta_H}d\theta\\
&= d(p^2) + i_{\Delta_H} dp \wedge dq\\
&= \left(\frac{\partial (p^2)}{\partial q}dq + \frac{\partial (p^2)}{\partial p} dp\right) + (-q\,dq - p\,dp)\\
&= 2p\,dp + (-q\,dq - p\,dp)\\
L_{\Delta_H}(\theta)&= p\,dp - q\,dq = d\left(\frac{p^2}{2}-\frac{q^2}{2}\right).
\end{align}$$

This is consistent with the Euler-Lagrange equation usually defined on the tangent bundle $T\mathbb{Q}$ for the Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}(q,\dot{q}) = \dot{q}^2/2 - q^2/2$. This one makes sense to me.

=== #2: LIE DERIVATIVE ON $T(T^*\mathbb{Q})$ ===

However, I could also interpret $\theta$ as a one-form on $T(T^*Q)$ and study its flow with respect to the field $\Delta_T$. To be precise, I could calculate the Lie derivative on $T(T^*\mathbb{Q})$ in the following way:

$$\begin{align}
L_{\Delta_T}(\theta) &= d(i_{\Delta_T}\theta) + i_{\Delta_T}d\theta, \\
&= d(p\dot{q}) + i_{\Delta_T}(dp\wedge dq), \\
&= \left[\frac{(p\dot{q})}{\partial q}dq + \frac{(p\dot{q})}{\partial p}dp + \frac{(p\dot{q})}{\partial \dot{q}}d\dot{q} + \frac{(p\dot{q})}{\partial \dot{p}}d\dot{p}\right] + (\dot{p}\,dq - \dot{q}\,dp), \\
&= (\dot{q}\,dp + p\,d\dot{q}) + (\dot{p}\,dq - \dot{q}\,dp), \\
L_{\Delta_T}(\theta) &= p\,d\dot{q} + \dot{p}\,dq.
\end{align}$$

If we enforce the constraint $\dot{q} = p$ and $\dot{p} = -q$ from Hamilton's equations, we get the same result as in #1,

$$L_{\Delta_T}(\theta) = p\,dp - q\,dq.$$

So the first two calculations look consistent.

=== #3: SEEMINGLY MIXED APPROACH ===

Here we can again consider $\theta$ as a one-form on $T^* \mathbb{Q}$, but we try to calculate the Lie derivative with respect to the field $\Delta_T$ defined on $T(T^*\mathbb{Q})$. Naively,

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{aligned}
L_{\Delta_T}(\theta) &= d(i_{\Delta_T}\theta) + i_{\Delta_T}(d\theta) \\
&= d(p\dot{q}) + i_{\Delta_T}(dp \wedge dq) \\
&= \left(\frac{\partial (p \dot{q})}{\partial q}dq + \frac{\partial (p \dot{q})}{\partial p} dp \right) + \left(\dot{p}\,dq - \dot{q}\,dp \right) \\
&= \left[ \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial q} \dot{q} + p \frac{\partial \dot{q}}{\partial q}\right) dq + \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial p} \dot{q} + p \frac{\partial \dot{q}}{\partial p} \right) dp \right] + \left(\dot{p}\,dq - \dot{q}\,dp \right) \\
&= \dot{q} dp + \left(\dot{p}\,dq - \dot{q}\,dp \right) \\
L_{\Delta_T}(\theta) &= \dot{p}\,dq.
\end{aligned}
\end{align}
$$

Here, the difference is that terms like $d\dot{q}$ and $d\dot{p}$ are not included in the differential because we work on $T^*\mathbb{Q}$. Moreover, the derivatives of $\dot{q}$ and $\dot{p}$ are interpreted as:

$$\frac{\partial \dot{q}}{\partial q} = \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial{q}}{\partial{q}}\right) = \frac{d}{dt} \left( 1 \right) = 0,\;\;\textrm{and}\;\;\frac{\partial \dot{p}}{\partial q} = \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial{p}}{\partial{q}}\right) = \frac{d}{dt} \left( 0 \right) = 0$$

where $d/dt$ is the total time derivative along the flow. Note that if I set the constraint $\dot{p} = -q$, I get $L_{\Delta_T}(\theta) = -q\,dq$. This is *not* the same as in #1 and #2.

I saw someone more knowledgeable than me perform this last calculation. But it seems very fishy to me and I can't find a good interpretation for it. Can anyone make sense of it in some context? Or is it just a plain mistake on their part?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In #3, what does $\dot q$ mean if you're working only on $T^*Q$?

Comment: Yes, that's why I think it's fishy. The way out is to interpret $\dot{q}$ as a function of $(q,p)$ on a given phase space trajectory, which is basically what I did in #1. But then if you do that you can't pretend that $\partial \dot{q}/\partial{q}$ and $\partial \dot{q}/\partial{p}$ vanish. So I really don't see a way to consistently interpret this.

Comment: Not to mention that the result in #2 really resembles what you would expect just from informal common sense and the chain rule for time derivatives: $\dot{(p dq)} = \dot{p} dq + p \dot{(dq)}$. It seems that #3 is just ignoring the variation of the basis covector $dq$ along the flow. This should be just as unacceptable as neglecting the variation of the basis tangent vectors.